# Using Polymer with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, polymer

I'm trying to understand what will be the best way to use polymer with angularjs.  I want the MVC powers of angular with the declarative simplicity of polymer elements.  My two thought processes are to completely forego angular directives and only use polymer, or to wrap the polymer in a directive.  The latter seems like it would work better with data binding and complex scope attributes, but may make the beauty of polymer a moot point since it's no longer very declarative at that point.

Thoughts?  What's the best way to merge these two worlds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been down that road before and, as far as I know, Angular.JS 2 will address this scenario someway. In the meantime, I suggest you try [ngPolymer](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-polymer-elements)

Comment: Seems interesting! Have anyone tried it on a real project?

Answer (score 3):

With upcoming Angular2, the usage of `polymer` as `webcomponents` is going to be smoother and easier than with Angular1.

Please refer to the `References` section of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971421/893612).

This contains how can a project take best out of `Angular2 & Polymer` both at the same time.