# polymer and angular use together

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I start learning recently polymer.

I want to hear yours opinion if its make sense to use both frameworks polymer and angular together or not and if polymer is really ready for production and what is your choice?

Answer (score 1):

**Polymer and Angular Together**

Yes, of-course they both can be used independently as well as together. Actually they both are two different things and to serve two different purposes, Though they have some common features to offer.

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32971421/893612) for a detailed explanation. It covers more things and tells about how Polymer & Angular both can be used as part of the same project.

---

**Polymer for Production**

With the release of `Polymer 1.0`, they claim it to be the production ready and as per them they have focussed more on the speed and efficiency this time. As a major change of this release they have replaced the `shadow dom` with `shady dom`.

Finger Crossed, I am also intending to use it in my project. Though I have heard very little of it being used in Production by others.

Answer (score 0):

I think Yes, is not a bad choice ! For example i try to use Angular for the little bit complex Service like the Auth Token Authentication, and Polymer for the others ! I want to use Material Design and the right choice is Polymer throught the Paper Element, i tried ngMaterial but is not so good like the Material in Polymer .... so my Answer for the Moment is Yes !